# r ggpredict warning , could not recover model data from environment

Tags: r, purrr, predict

I have several linear models in a list, like this below

```
data("mtcars")
head(mtcars)

mtcars_lm <- plyr::dlply(mtcars,
                           "cyl",
                             function(x) 
                                lm(mpg ~ hp + wt , data =x, na.action = na.omit))
```

I am trying to plot the marginal_effects for `wt` for each cylinder.

So I started with this.

```
predict_wt <- purrr::map(mtcars_lm , 
                            function(x)ggpredict(x, "wt"))
```

I am getting a warning, that says

```
Warning:Could not recover data from environment. Please make sure your data is available in your workspace. 
Trying to retrieve data from the model frame now.
```

Not sure how to investigate the root cause of this warning and fix this. Any suggestion is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Adopting the approach here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/vignettes/broom_and_dplyr.html

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>%
  nest(data = -cyl) %>%
  mutate(wt = map(data, ~ lm(mpg ~ hp + wt, data = .x)),
         tidied = map(wt, broom::tidy)) %>%
  unnest(tidied) %>%
  filter(term == "wt") %>%
  ggplot(aes(factor(cyl), estimate)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = estimate + std.error,
                    ymin = estimate - std.error))
```

[image]